# Add jpeg2000 in a postgresql DB

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal, postgresql

I am trying to add a jpeg200 image to my postgresql database.
Problem: this format is not implemented by default in postgresql/postgis which uses the gdal library.

After some research, I found that jp2 needs another library http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html (named libjasper). I've managed to get a dll of it but I have no clue where to put it, so far I've tried in \bin and \lib in the postrgresql's repository but no luck so far.

Then, I've found I need the dll compiled with the same compiler as postgis.

Has anyone been confronted with this problem before?

I could make my way around by converting my jp2 into tiff (ogr, qgis, arcgis) but as you may know tiff are way bigger than jpeg2000.

Comment: Forget Jasper because it is useless for any bigger JPEG2000 images. A good open source alternative is OpenJPEG http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jp2openjpeg.html. And what you say about much bigger tiff files is true only if you create uncompressed tiffs. Tiffs with internal JPEG compression have comparable sizes. See http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html and use TILED=YES and COMPRESS=JPEG.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I'll still have have to compile it again so it could work adding OpenJPEG right? I think I'd better get myself on qgis server for this one, since those rasters are destined to web visualization